# if文での配列の取り扱い方について

Tags: ruby

初質問失礼します。
rubyでif文を記述する際、1つの配列のすべての要素を同じ条件式に格納して、andで結びたいです。

```
if hoge[0]!="" and hoge[1]!="" and hoge[2]!=""..  then
```

というようにです。しかし、配列全てに対してこのような記述をすると、あまりにも長くなりすぎてしまいます。
そこで、以下のような記述ができないだろうかと試してみました。a~zは変数です。

```
hoge=[a,b,c,d,..z]
if hoge[0..-1] != "" then
    puts "all exist"
else
    puts "foo"
end
```

出力結果：
変数a~zの値が全て "" の時でも、どこかに値が入っている時でも、"all exist"が出力されました。
どうしてこのような出力結果になったかも私にはよく分かりませんでした。

1つの配列の条件式を全てandで結びたい場合に、何か良い記述の方法はないでしょうか。
よろしければ、私の記述方法が間違っている理由も教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

この場合は`all?`を使うのがいちばん素直な方法だと思います。

```
if hoge.all? {|item| item!=""}
  puts "all exist"
else
  puts "foo"
end
```

> そこで、以下のような記述ができないだろうかと試してみました。a~zは変数です。
>
> ```
> hoge=[a,b,c,d,..z]
> if hoge[0..-1] != "" then
>     puts "all exist"
> else
>     puts "foo"
> end
> ```
>
> 出力結果： 変数a~zの値が全て "" の時でも、どこかに値が入っている時でも、"all exist"が出力されました。
>   どうしてこのような出力結果になったかも私にはよく分かりませんでした。

`hoge[0..-1]`という表現は「hogeの1番最初の要素」から「hogeの後ろから1番目の要素」までの配列を返します。つまりhogeと同じものを返します。

hogeは配列であって文字列ではないので、hogeの中身に関わらず`hoge[0..-1] != ""`は常に真となります。

Answer (score 3):

配列中に一つでも空の要素があれば "foo" を出力し、そうでなければ "all exist" を出力したいということであれば、次のようにすればできます。

```
if hoge.any?(&:empty?)
  puts "foo"
else
  puts "all exist"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`inject`で頑張るとできそうな気がしました（条件部分があってるかはやや自信なし。。）

```
if hoge.inject {|ret, i| ret && i != ""} then
    puts "all exist"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1行で書くならこんな感じですね。

```
puts hoge.any?(&:empty?) ? 'foo' : 'all exist'
```

もしくはこう。

```
puts hoge.none?(&:empty?) ? 'all exist' : 'foo'
```

ついでにこんなパターンも

```
 puts hoge.count("").zero? ? 'all exist' : 'foo'
```

確認用に書いたテスト（Minitest）も載せておきます。

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe Array do
  let(:all_empty) { ['', '', '']}
  let(:all_exist) { ['1', '2', '3']}
  let(:mixed) { ['1', '', '3']}

  def all_ok?
    ->{ans(all_empty)}.must_output "foo\n"
    ->{ans(all_exist)}.must_output "all exist\n"
    ->{ans(mixed)}.must_output "foo\n"
  end

  it do
    def ans(hoge)
      puts hoge.count("").zero? ? 'all exist' : 'foo'
    end
    all_ok?
  end

  it do
    def ans(hoge)
      puts hoge.none?(&:empty?) ? 'all exist' : 'foo'
    end
    all_ok?
  end

  it do
    def ans(hoge)
      puts hoge.any?(&:empty?) ? 'foo' : 'all exist'
    end
    all_ok?
  end
end
```